# getElementById(php variable) is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a list created as a result of mysql query and several `<li>` with unique ID as variable.

When I want to put this ID in `getElementById(<?php $id?>)` it does not work. I have tried all quotations but not works.

Here is the code;

```
<ul >
<?php
  $query= mysqli_query($con,"Select * from database order by date ASC");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){?>
  <li onclick="showMlstone(this.value)" value="<?php echo $row[id];?>"><?php echo $row[name];?><p id=<?php echo $row[id];?>></p></li>
  <script>
  function showMlstone(int) {
    var xhttp;
      if (int == "") {
      document.getElementById(<?php echo $row[id];?>).innerHTML = "";
      return;
    }
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById(<?php echo $row[id]?>).innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "get.php?q="+int, true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
  </script>
<?php
</ul>
```

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how all of this works / is supposed to do, but i just wanted to point out that your are missing a semicolon on this line in the php echo:

```
document.getElementById(<?php echo $row[id]?>).innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

And your php while has no closing bracket.

Comment: Thanks. I put semicolon however it still does not work. My problem is I can not assign a variable to getelementbyid(). When I check it from chrome review, it seems the value inside getelementbyid() is correct but it does not work.

Comment: What about the closing bracket for the while loop ?

Comment: Also, you can't write $row[id] , is id a mysql column ? in that case go for $row["id"], is it a js int ? in that case, i can't really thing of a way of doing it, except exploding the php array into a js object

Answer (score 0):

Try with quotes:

```
document.getElementById("<?php echo $row['id']?>").innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have *.php file, which includes php code and other different language - use open and close php tag.

```
<?php
// php code here
?>

<!-- Some html here -->
```

Also you can use short syntax - the best way to combine html and php code:

```
<ul>
    <li><?= $variable ?></li>
</ul>
```

Try to use `<?=` instead `<?php echo` - this is the same, but **first is better** and **more readable**.

2. In you case you can move your php code to top of the file, then use php variables to insert then in html code below, something like that:

```
<?php

$query = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from database order by date ASC");

$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

?>

<ul>
    <? foreach($rows as $row): ?>
        <li>
            <?=$row['id']?>
        </li>
    <? endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Do not forget to write `$row['id']` instead `$row[id]`, and do everything, that may optimize your code, and made it more readable for you and other people in stackoverflow :)

Useful links for you:

- [Short and alternate syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. It may work

```
document.getElementById('<?php echo $row[id]; ?>').innerHTML = this.responseText;
```